# Exception when training relation extractor model from StanfordNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to train my own model for the relation extractor feature from StanfordNLP as described here : http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.shtml. The issue is that when I start the training I get the following exception:

```
PERCENTAGE OF TRAIN: 1.0
The reader log level is set to SEVERE
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.0 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ...done [0.9 sec].
Mar 25, 2015 9:23:36 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading makeResultsPrinters
INFO: Making result printers from
Mar 25, 2015 9:23:36 PM edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading makeResultsPrinters
INFO: Making result printers from edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.makeResultsPrinters(MachineReading.java:771)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.makeResultsPrinters(MachineReading.java:756)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.makeMachineReading(MachineReading.java:235)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.main(MachineReading.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.MachineReading.makeResultsPrinters(MachineReading.java:768)
        ... 3 more
```

I'm using StanfordNLP 3.5.1 and indeed the class does not exist in the jar. I am using the roth.properties file as described in the link at the top and that contains the line:

```
relationResultsPrinters = edu.stanford.nlp.ie.machinereading.RelationExtractorResultsPrinter
```

I tried commenting out that line with the hope that the code will pick up the default printer but that is still RelationExtractorResultsPrinter.

Anyone got this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely our bad! This class will be included in the next release. For now, you can compile the class from the [source distribution (GitHub link)](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/machinereading/RelationExtractorResultsPrinter.java).

Comment: You mean building the jar myself with all the sources from github? Or you had something else in mind only with that class?

Comment: I think he means building the jar yourself. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/basic-compiling.txt

Comment: The instructions from the link are incomplete since after you unpack to the scr folder there is no build.xml to use. I got the one from Github but then you need the rest of the artifacts like commonbuildjsp.xml and the test folder, etc. Once again, did you mean downloading the sources from github or is there another quicker way?

Comment: Quickest way (untested, but should work): download the `.java` file from my link and drop it into the unzipped `src` folder (created using instructions that Sonal posted). Then run `javac` on the single downloaded `.java` file; make sure all the `.jar` files in the CoreNLP distribution are on your classpath. Then move the resulting `.class` into the `.jar`.

Comment: This is a bit of a hassle, sorry! We'll have another release in less than a month, in which this problem will be resolved.